# Illegal string offset 'taxonomy' in

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I'm struggling a bit with the following error

```
Illegal string offset 'taxonomy' in ...  on line 175
Trying to get property of non-object in ... on line 177
Trying to get property of non-object in ... on line 178
```

The code I'm using is:

```
function tax_cat_active( $output, $args ) {

  if(is_single()){
    global $post;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $args['taxonomy'] );
    foreach( $terms as $term )
        if ( preg_match( '#cat-item-' . $term ->term_id . '#', $output ) )
            $output = str_replace('cat-item-'.$term ->term_id, 'cat-item-'.$term ->term_id . ' current-cat', $output);
  }

  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'tax_cat_active', 10, 2 );
```

Anyone an idea on how to solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem comes from:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $args['taxonomy'] );
```

i.e. you have to make sure it's not `false` or  `WP_Error` object.

You should also check the output of:

```
var_dump( $args );
```

Try for example:

```
if( ! is_array( $terms ) )
    return $output;
```

or

```
if( ! $terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
    return $output;
```

before your loop.